# Symfony2 - Custom repository not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, repository

I've this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'gsyle39\VideothequeBundle\Repository\GenreRepository' not found in C:\wamp\www\Videotheque\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php on line 578

Nevertheless, I add the name of the repository class to the mapping definition of my entity :

```
/**
* gsyle39\VideoThequeBundle\Entity\Genre
*
* @ORM\Table()
*
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="gsyle39\VideothequeBundle\Repository\GenreRepository")
*/
class Genre
{
   ...
}
```

Here is my GenreRepository :

```
<?php

namespace gstyle39\VideothequeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * GenreRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class GenreRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function myfindAll()
    {
        $genres = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder('g')
            // leftJoin because I need all the genre
            ->leftJoin('g.films', 'f')
            ->addSelect('COUNT(f)')
            ->groupBy('g')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();

        // $genres contains all the genres and the associated movies
        return ($genres);
    }
}
```

And finally this is the method in my controller I use for calling my custome "findALL" :

```
public function getListGenresAction(){

        $liste_genres = $this->getDoctrine()
                             ->getEntityManager()
                             ->getRepository('gstyle39VideothequeBundle:Genre')
                             ->myFindAll;

        return $this->render('gstyle39VideothequeBundle:Videotheque:test.html.twig', array(
            'genres' => $liste_genres
        ));
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your repository has as namespace `namespace gstyle39\VideothequeBundle\Entity;` and the annotation says it should be `namespace gstyle39\VideothequeBundle\Repository;`.

Also, make sure you put it under `src/gstyle39/VideothequeBundle/Repository` directory.

Comment: You are right, I had a wrong namespace but it doesn't solve the problem :s

Comment: Try to delete `app/cache/*` folders and reload the application.

Comment: It's in the directory I commented? If so, is the error still the same? Double-check folder names, including upper-case/lower-case letters, match the namespace. Also I noticed i had a typo in the directory I said.